# How to change path in SolrClient

Tags: php, solr, solrclient

Regarding [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/solrclient.construct.php) one has to set the path (i.e. core) on initialization of `SolrClient`:

```
$client = new SolrClient([
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 8983,
    'path' => '/solr/coreXYZ',
]);
```

As I need access to multiple cores (ex. `/solr/core_1`, `/solr/core_2`), is there any way to dynamically change the path? I was not able to find any option for `query` or `request` method.

**Edit**

I found a way which worked also:

```
$client->setServlet(SolrClient::SEARCH_SERVLET_TYPE, '../' . $core . '/select');
$client->setServlet(SolrClient::UPDATE_SERVLET_TYPE, '../' . $core . '/update');
```

But this is a dirty hack only for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a factory method and return different objects depending on which core you're accessing. Keeping object state that changes between which core you're requesting without being set explicitly through the query method is a recipe for weird bugs.

Something like the following pseudo-ish code (I don't have the Solr extension available, so I wasn't able to test this):

```
class SolrClientFactory {
    protected $cache = [];
    protected $commonOptions = [];

    public function __construct($common) {
        $this->commonOptions = $common;
    }

    public function getClient($core) {
        if (isset($this->cache[$core])) {
            return $this->cache[$core];
        }

        $opts = $this->commonOptions;

        // assumes $path is given as '/solr/'
        $opts['path'] .= $core;

        $this->cache[$core] = new SolrClient($opts);
        return $this->cache[$core];
    }
}

$factory = new SolrClientFactory([
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 8983,
    'path' => '/solr/',
]);

$client = $factory->getClient('coreXYZ');
```

Comment: Yesterday, I tried a dirty hack: `$client->setServlet(SolrClient::SEARCH_SERVLET_TYPE, '../' . $core . '/select');` which worked also, but yours is much more better. Thanks